# Failing to push local repository to github

Tags: git, github, repository, push

I started learning git two three days back and since yesterday I am facing problem pushing contents to git. So today morning, I deleted everything from my comp and github account and tried to do everything from scratch following [this tutorial](http://nithinbekal.com/2010/installing-git-and-pushing-repo-to-github/). But after I do that I more or less land in the same problem. I've seen for solutions on stackoverflow and other forums, but I couldn't bail myself out of the trouble.

I have a repo called project on github and on my local machine d drive with two text files which I am trying to push to github. Please help.

Comment: Did you already tried `git pull` as hinted in the logs?

Comment: Okay, I did a git pull just now and I still get the same problem

Comment: Do a `git status` and update the question with the output.

Comment: #on  branch master, nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: I've spotted a problem. The key in the shell doesn't match with the key I created and added to my github account. How do I rectify that now?

Comment: Just add your new public key to the github account and delete the old one (if it's not in use anywhere, which it probably shouldn't be).  Github allows multiple public keys, just like ssh in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it worked. Thank you fmendez for your suggestions.

```
  git checkout master
 git push origin +HEAD
```

If anyone has any better solutions, please chip in.

Comment: That usually happens when the remote repository (your github repo in this case) has been either edited directly or been pushed to from another user/repo. Doing git pull, git push usually solves it just fine. git checkout master works fine as well.

Comment: Be aware that `git pull` `git push` if you have local commits and there are non-incorporated remote commits will cause a merge commit to occur and sometimes force others to deal with your conflicts.  The proper thing to do if someone has put changes up to master to keep the history linear is usually to `git fetch;git rebase origin/master` to ensure that -you- resolve any conflicts in your latest commits instead of making ugly merge commits on master.